# Error ListBox scroll up - down with DrawItem

Tags: c#, winforms

I don't know for sure about my ListBox, I have created one Listbox with Items, It's okay when I scroll up-down,but when I drawItem Image ( Image + Item Name) in addition I saw image with Item name, but has problem when scroll up - down.

what's problem?

Comment: My code is complicated, Because I get the SkypeKit.NET Tutorial 8, 

Skype tutorial 8 talking about conversation, but skype provide conversation list no avatar image and avialability, conversatoin name only!, I want to customize drawItem AvatarImage with Availability in ListBox, Now that listbox already draw, but error when I scroll listbox up-down, I don't no what happen when I scroll on it.

Comment: I had similar problem. Have you got something like that: `MyListBoxItem item = listBox1.Items[e.Index] as MyListBoxItem;` `if (item != null) {e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Message, listBox1.Font, SolidBrush(item.ItemColor), 0, e.Index * listBox1.ItemHeight); }` ?

Comment: Yes, Its' similar your, see the follow code:

   e.Graphics.DrawString(convers.P_DISPLAYNAME, e.Font, textBrush, e.Bounds.Left + 20, e.Bounds.Top + 5);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(getContactImage(convers), e.Bounds.Left + 5, e.Bounds.Top + 5, 14, 14);

Comment: Not sure, but i bet there is something wrong with `getContactImage(convers)`.

Comment: Try it like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dbsak4dc.aspx and you will see, if the problem is stil there

Comment: Function getContactImage(convers) is a function get Image name that return like that : image.jpg, I was follow up with this code also,

Image newImage = Image.FromFile("SampImag.jpg");

    // Create coordinates for upper-left corner.

    // of image and for size of image.
    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;
    int width = 450;
    int height = 150;

    // Draw image to screen.
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, x, y, width, height);

Comment: And still the same problem? If is, then sorry, i don't know what's wrong.Should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a `ListView` instead of a `ListBox` similar as http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13006/Extended-ListView  or  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524138/please-help-to-draw-border-for-image-in-listview)

Comment: A `ListView` is a specialized `ListBox`, so `ListBox` should be easyer. I recommend to try it. Here is some differences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227231/wpf-listbox-vs-listview-how-to-choose-for-data-binding, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703641/the-difference-between-listbox-and-listview and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/wpf/thread/a89bea6e-31f6-483d-a7a2-252aca799f15